# How to Optimize this form validation

Tags: php, forms, oop

> learning php oop;
>    This Code suppose to validate and make form sticky ( keeps values of
>   field after submission of  the form ); I have
>   used 3 functions:
>     1-startForm() 2-validateForm() 3-viewform()

1. startForm():
   Entry point to  my application , Just to call viewForm()
2. validateForm() : check if form posted $_POST[], then validate and store all the form values in array .
3. viewform() :  echo html form in herdoc style .

> code works fine and validate user's inputs. Still it is not perfect !.
>
> Question : How to optimize this peace of code ? .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>`enter code here`
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>

         <?php

          include('./formHandling.php');
        // call startForm () function to start form
          startForm();
            ?>

        </body>
    </html>
```

> php code file // formHandling.php

```
     <?php
        function startForm(){ 
        viewform();
         }



        // view form in herdoc style 
        function viewform() {

          list($stickFormInputs2,$errors) = validateForm();

          if(!empty($errors)){
            foreach($errors as $key => $value ){

          }}



            print<<<_FORM_
                 <form method='POST' action="./form.php">

                <p><input type="text" name="user_name"  value="{$stickFormInputs2['user_name']}" ></p>
                <p><input type="email" name="email"  value="{$stickFormInputs2['email']} " ></p>

                <p> 
                     <label for="" > Subscibe for newsletter ? </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="1" {$stickFormInputs2['subscribe']} />
                </p>

                <p>which country do you have visited ?
                    <input type="checkbox" name="county[]" value="uk"   {$stickFormInputs2['uk'] }/>UK<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="county[]" value="usa" {$stickFormInputs2['usa'] } />USA<br />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="county[]" value="uae"  {$stickFormInputs2['uae'] }  />UAE<br />
               </p>



                <p> this  is the drop down list  </p>
                    <p>
                    <select name='major' >
                    <option value='0'>SELECT ONE </option>
                    <option value='cs'  {$stickFormInputs2['cs'] }> CS </option>
                    <option value='cis' {$stickFormInputs2['cis'] }> CIS </option>
                    <option value='sw' {$stickFormInputs2['sw'] }> SW </option>
                    <option value="bis" {$stickFormInputs2['bis'] } > BIS </option>
                       </select>
                </p>



                 <p>
                    which car  you will use ?
                    <input type="radio" name="car" value="bmw" {$stickFormInputs2['bmw'] }>BMW
                    <input type="radio" name="car" value="audi"    {$stickFormInputs2['audi'] }>AUDI
                    <input type="radio" name="car" value="porsh" {$stickFormInputs2['porsh'] }>PORSH
               </p>


                <input type="submit" value="submit">

                </form> 
        _FORM_;
        }


// validate form and return array of inputs and errors 
 function validateForm() {

            $inputs = array();
            $errors = array();
            // defaults values 
            $inputs = array(
                'user_name'=>'',
                 'email'=>'',
                 'subscribe'=>'',
                 'uk'=>'',
                 'usa'=>'',
                 'uae'=>'',
                 'cs'=>'',
                 'cis'=>'',
                 'sw'=>'',
                 'bis'=>'',
                 'bmw'=>'',
                 'audi'=>'',
                'porsh'=>'',
                   );


            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
            // Check user_name
            if (!isset($_POST['user_name']) || strlen(trim($_POST['user_name'])) == 0) {
                $errors[] = ' ::::::::::::::::::::: Enter your name . name Required';
            } else {
                $inputs['user_name']  = htmlentities(strip_tags($_POST['user_name']));

                echo "<br/>user name is OK from ValidatForm() : " . $inputs['user_name'];
            }


            // Check EMAIL
            if (!isset($_POST['email']) || strlen(trim($_POST['email'])) == 0) {
                $errors[] = ' ::::::::::::::::::::: Enter your EMAIL . EMAIL Required';
            } else {

                if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

                    $inputs['email'] =  htmlentities(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));
                    echo "<br/> email is OK from ValidatForm() : {" . $inputs['email'] . "}";
                } else {
                    $errors[] = ' ::::::::::::::::::::: Your Email is Not Valid ! from FormValidate()';
                }
            }


            // Check subscribe check box
            if (!isset($_POST['subscribe']) || empty($_POST['subscribe'] )) {

                $errors[] = " ::::::::::::::::::::: Subscribe is not checked " ;
            } else {
                $inputs['subscribe'] = 'checked';
                echo "<br/>User want to subscribe in our newsletter ValidatForm() : " . $inputs['subscribe'];
            }



            if (isset($_POST['county']) && !empty($_POST['county'])) {

                foreach ($_POST['county'] as $county) {

                    if ($county == "uk") {
                        $inputs['uk'] = "checked";
                    }

                    if ($county == "usa") {
                        $inputs['usa'] = "checked";
                    }

                    if ($county == "uae") {
                        $inputs['uae'] = "checked";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $errors[] = ' ::::::::::::::::::::: Select Country ! ';
            }




            // Check Dropdown menu
            if (isset($_POST['major']) && !empty($_POST['major'])) {

                switch ($_POST['major']) {
                    case "cs": $inputs['cs'] = "selected";
                        break;
                    case "cis":$inputs['cis'] = "selected";
                        break;
                    case "sw":$inputs['sw'] = "selected";
                        break;
                    case "bis":$inputs['bis'] = "selected";
                        break;
                }
            } else {

                $errors[] = " ::::::::::::::::::::: SELECT FORM DROP DOWN MENU major";
            }





            //chack radio buttons CAR
            if (isset($_POST['car']) && !empty($_POST['car'])) {

                switch ($_POST['car']) {
                    case "bmw": $inputs['bmw'] = "checked";
                        break;
                    case "audi":$inputs['audi'] = "checked";
                        break;
                    case "porsh":$inputs['porsh'] = "checked";
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                $errors[] = " ::::::::::::::::::::: You must choose a car to be for you  in this trip !";
            }

            }

            return array($inputs, $errors);
        }
```

Comment: Seeing `htmlentities(strip_tags(...))` in this code is always concerning. That is absolutely not in any way a way of preventing [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It looks like you’re in the process of writing your own Object Relationship Manager (ORM). PHP already has many of these which are tested, documented, and have considerable community support. Have a look at  [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) and [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent) before re-inventing the wheel. This code has a number of very serious issues that will be very time-consuming to properly resolve.